# Are 'wp_ajax' and 'wp_ajax_nopriv' exclusive to authenticated and non-authenticated users?

Tags: ajax, actions

Basically what I'm asking is, is `wp_ajax_nopriv` exclusive to non-logged-in users?

Will a `wp_ajax_nopriv` action fire if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [the WordPress source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L114), I'd say that `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` fires *only* if you're not logged in, and `wp_ajax_*` fires otherwise.

Here's the relevant bit, in `admin-ajax.php`, lines 85-115 in version 5.0.3:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
    if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        wp_die( '0', 400 );
    }

    /**
     * Fires authenticated Ajax actions for logged-in users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
    // If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
    if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        wp_die( '0', 400 );
    }

    /**
     * Fires non-authenticated Ajax actions for logged-out users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
```

So, if you're logged in (ie, `is_user_logged_in()` is `true`), it runs the `wp_ajax_*` action(s), otherwise it runs the `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` actions.

If you want the same action run regardless whether your user is logged in or not, I'd recommend you hook to **both** `wp_ajax_*` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_*`.

Answer (score 3):

As per `wp_ajax_(action)` [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)):

> This hook is functionally the same as [`wp_ajax_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)), except the
>   "nopriv" variant is used for handling AJAX requests from
>   unauthenticated users, i.e. when [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) returns false.

[`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) determines whether the current visitor is a logged in user. It will return `true` if user is logged in, `false` if not logged in.